# Near-Field Scanning Optical Microscope

Tags: microscopy

Is it possible to study chemistry of a material (Like chemical composition) using Near-Field Scanning Optical Microscope?

Is it possible to go below 10nm in NSOM/SNOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can extract high resolution chemical composition information using NSOM/SNOM by performing high resolution infrared or optical spectroscopy.

My experience (some years ago now..) was with tip enhanced scattering scanning near-field optical microscopy (sSNOM). At that time resolution was limited to ~10 nm because that was the smallest dimension which could reasonably be realized for sSNOM tip fabrication. This isn't a fundamental limit but I think a lot of technical complications would come in in trying to fabricated smaller tips to get higher resolution.

Comment: Can you please suggest some journals where they have performed chemical composition using That?

Comment: See the articles on Anasys instruments (commercial sSNOM) webpage: https://www.anasysinstruments.com/featured-publications/